# How to use a JSON file to aggregate in MongoDB in Java?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using the Java MongoDB driver v4.3:

```
implementation group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongodb-driver-sync', version: '4.3.1'
implementation group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'bson', version: '4.3.1'
```

I have my aggregation pipelines written in JSON files which are placed in the `src/main/resources` folder. The `aggregate` function only accepts a `List<Bson>`.  After fetching the file, how do I pass it into the MongoDB method?

```
String fileName = "physics/test.json";
File file = new File(fileName);
MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
MongoCollection collection = db.getCollection(collectionName);
// Convert file to List<Bson> ???
AggregateIterable sourceList = collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Comment: I don't believe there are any converters that will convert JSON to Java-based aggregation pipelines.  In Atlas, there is a code converter, but this is expected to be a design-time implementation, not a run-time implementation.

Comment: The aggregate pipeline is an array of aggregation stages - and in Java this is a `List` of stages - each stage defined as `Bson` or its implementation `org.bson.Document`. You may want to tell what the contents of the file look like. Maybe you can read the file and convert it into the `List`.

Comment: @prasad_ I have many files which have aggregations that consists of lots of pipelines. One pipeline is like this:

`[{"$group":{"_id":{"segment":"$segment","invoice_id":{"$trim":{"input":"$invoice_id"}}},"qty":{"$sum":"$qty"}}}]`

Comment: Thats native code (and its a JSON string). You may have to parse it to instances of `Bson`. The `Document` class has some methods like `parse`.

Comment: @prasad_ How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
import org.bson.json.JsonObject;
// ...
    
String json = """
        [{"$group":{"_id":{"segment":"$segment","invoice_id":{"$trim":{"input":"$invoice_id"}}},"qty":{"$sum":"$qty"}}}]""";

List<BsonDocument> pipeline = new BsonArrayCodec().decode(new JsonReader(json), DecoderContext.builder().build())
        .stream().map(BsonValue::asDocument)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

MongoClient client = new MongoClient();

List<JsonObject> results = client.getDatabase("test").getCollection("test").withDocumentClass(JsonObject.class)
        .aggregate(pipeline).into(new ArrayList<>());

for (JsonObject cur: results) {
    System.out.println(cur.getJson());
}
```

Comment: This will fail in case the JSON contains datetimes, because there are treated like strings not ISODate(). And it will fail if you are using constants like ISODate() because this is not a valid JSON anymore.